# How to place a Futures Market order with Take Profit and Stop Loss using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bots, algorithmic-trading, back-testing

I'm using backtesting package for testing my trading bot but struggling to place Take Profit order along with buy order using python. Fow now I am using following python code for buy orders like:

```
    def support_trade_level(self, support, resistance, lower_support): 
        if self.close <= support + 1 and self.close >= support - 1:
            self.buy(sl= support - 2, 
                     limit= support, 
                     stop= support, 
                     tp= Support + 8)
```

In my code I set that close buy position when it give 8 points profit, and it work Ok, but when I try to reduce take profit and set it to below 7, it gave me ValueError (sl < limit < tp)

to remove this error I assign limit & stop prices along with sl and tp, it remove ValueError msg and allowed me to 7 points as take profit but in backend it completely eliminate take profit price and consider it as 0 so all of my trades closed in loss (I'm assuming that it set tp=0 because after that all of my trades closed in negative).

I want maximum 4 points per trade buy I don't understand why it is not allowing me to take less than 8 points profit. Any solution?